# F5 LTM Load balancer Rest Java Api?

Tags: f5, internal-load-balancer

One of my client using F5 BIP-IP LTM software load balancer. I need to access to this LB and I need to read this LB and need to add servers to this LB using Java Program. I'm new to this API. Can you please help me or provide me the api's like Soap, REST, Or Direct JDK for this f5 software load balancer.

Answer (score 3):

BIG-IP has a REST API called iControlREST.  F5's API documentation is on DevCentral.f5.com and is registration-required for API documentation.

[DevCentral iControlREST Home](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControlREST.HomePage.ashx)

You'll need to know what version of BIG-IP you're running as there may be some commands you'll not have access to if you're on an older version.  The API user guides and reference material for downloading are also available on this page in addition to code examples for unique commands.

Someone may also already have the code you're looking for on the [Codeshare](https://devcentral.f5.com/codeshare) area of DevCentral too (again, login required).

Comment: We do have a getting started with iControl series as well that has some java examples for the SOAP interface (3rd article): https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/getting-started-with-icontrol-history-20463